# Flexbox not working in FireFox version 37.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

`CSS` display `flex` is working in all browsers excluding `FireFox` version `37.0.1`.

```
body .center-it{
     /*older flexbox*/

    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    /*newer flexbox*/

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in on  FX 37.01 and it works fine. This can't not be verified. This is tested under window 8 64 bit architecture

Can somebody verify  on different operating system or same OS

Any body can take a look at the

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c953szq4/)

```
<div class="center-it">Message Here for Alan M</div>
```